# How to stop infinite loop after the end of post list? Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, infinite-loop

I build custom infinite loop for my blog. Everything is working great but if there is no posts to show then also my infinite loop is loading again and again with the other design parts. How to add conditions in my infinite loop so it can stop if post list ends.

**AJAX to load infinite loop**

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

        var post_page_count = 0;
        var height_scroll = 400;
            $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($('body').height() <= ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop())){

                $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        async: false,
                        url: "/loopa/infiloop.php",
                        data: {pcount:post_page_count},
                        success:
                        function(result){

                            $("#looppage").append(result);
                            }
                });
            post_page_count = post_page_count+20;

            }
});
});
</script>
```

**The Loop I am using:**

```
<?php

$infinite_loop= $_POST['pcount'];  ?>

<?php require('../wp-config.php');
$wp->init();
$wp->parse_request();
$wp->query_posts();
$wp->register_globals(); ?>

      <div class="myclass" role="main">
            <?php
                    global $wpdb;
                    $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 20, 'order' => 'DESC', 'offset'=>$infinite_loop, 'category' => 613);    
                    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
                    foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
                    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>


                        <div>
                            <div class="gizinfi-img"> 
                                <?php giz_featured_index(); ?> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="gizinfi-title">
                                <?php /* print $args['offset']; */ ?>
                                <?php giz_get_view( 'gizc', '_content', 'post-header' ); ?>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                    </article>
</div>
<?php if (!giz_wp_is_mobile() ) { ?>
 <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I dont see an infinite loop. all I see is a `foreach` which will be limited by the length of the array.  If you want to get out of the foreach early, just use `continue()`

Comment: I update my code, now you can see how i use infinite loop

Comment: still dont see an infinite loop.  You have a variable called `infinite_loop`. Also, where do you instantiate $wp?

Comment: I am not good in explaining, But I can try. there is a variable post_page_count where I store the number of posts which are already displayed on the call of scroll function. On the call of ajax I get the data from the loop page. In loop page I use this post_page_count as offset (limit) so I can exclude posts which are already displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `break`

```
<?php $baz = array('foo', 'bar', 'baz');
foreach ($baz as $foo) {
    echo $foo;
    if ($foo == 'bar') {
        break();
    }
} ?>
// I haven't tested it, but it should output `foo``bar` then break.
// just replace the if check with a check for the last element.
```

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

Answer (score 0):

Well I would say that this is not really an infinite loop, this is just the ajax being triggered without stop and this is triggered inclusive if there are no more posts left.
So to fix this :
`
    $(document).ready(function() {

```
    var post_page_count = 0;
    var height_scroll = 400;
    var no_more_posts = false;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if(no_more_posts) return;
        if ($('body').height() <= ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop())){

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                async: false,
                url: "/loopa/infiloop.php",
                data: {pcount:post_page_count},
                success:
                function(result){
                    if(result=="done"){
                        no_more_posts = true;
                    }else{                          
                        $("#looppage").append(result);
                    }
                }
            });
            post_page_count = post_page_count+20;

        }
    });
});
```

`Then:`

```
$infinite_loop= $_POST['pcount'];  ?>

<?php require('../wp-config.php');
$wp->init();
$wp->parse_request();
$wp->query_posts();
$wp->register_globals(); 
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 20, 'order' => 'DESC', 'offset'=>$infinite_loop, 'category' => 613);    
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
if(!$myposts->found_posts){
    echo "done";
    die;
}
?>


<div class="myclass" role="main">
    <?php
    global $wpdb;
    foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <div>
            <div class="gizinfi-img"> 
                <?php giz_featured_index(); ?> 
            </div>
            <div class="gizinfi-title">
                <?php /* print $args['offset']; */ ?>
                <?php giz_get_view( 'gizc', '_content', 'post-header' ); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata() ?>
</div>
<?php if (!giz_wp_is_mobile() ) { ?>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php } ?>`
```

Also there where a missing endforeach and I reset the postdata